# jqgrid's delGridRow not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to have a button in each row to delete the corresponding row. So I used the samples in the demo page to try to achieve this.

It is working for edit row, but I also want to have a delete button.

Here is my code

```
jQuery("#detFlex1").jqGrid({
    url: '<%= Html.Encode(ViewData["module"])%>/GetDetailList1',
    datatype: "json",
    altRows: true,
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames: ['Inv No', 'Actions', '<%= RmdReqVendor.AccountName %>', '<%= RmdReqVendor.AccountNum %>'
                , '<%= RmdReqVendor.Valuta %>'
                , '<%= RmdReqVendor.Country %>'
                , '<%= RmdReqVendor.Branch %>'
                , '<%= RmdReqVendor.BankKey %>'
                , '<%= RmdReqVendor.Priority %>'],
    colModel: [
           { name: 'account_id', index: 'account_id', width: 55, hidden: true },
           { name: 'act', index: 'act', width: 55, sortable: false },
           { name: 'account_name', index: 'account_name', width: 150,editable:true,editoptions:{size:30,maxlength:30}, editrules:{required:true} },
           { name: 'account_num', index: 'account_num', width: 150,editable:true,editoptions:{size:18,maxlength:18}, editrules:{required:true, number:true} },
           { name: 'valuta', index: 'valuta', width: 90, editable: true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"<%= JsHelper.CurrencyJsArray() %>"}, editrules:{required:true} },
           { name: 'country', index: 'country', width: 150, editable: true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"<%= JsHelper.CountryJsArray() %>"}, editrules:{required:true} },
           { name: 'branch', index: 'branch', width: 150,editable:true,editoptions:{size:40,maxlength:40}, editrules:{required:true} },
           { name: 'bank_key', index: 'bank_key', width: 90,editable:true,editoptions:{size:15,maxlength:15}, editrules:{required:false} },
           { name: 'priority', index: 'priority', width: 90,editable:true,editoptions:{size:10,maxlength:10}, editrules:{required:true, number:true} }
       ],
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    pager: '#pagerFlex1',
    sortname: 'request_id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption: '<%= RmdReqVendor.BankAccountTitle %>',
    width: $('.body').width()-40,
    height: 180,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    gridComplete: function(){
        var ids = jQuery("#detFlex1").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++){
            var cl = ids[i];
            be = "<button style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' title='Edit' onclick="jQuery('#detFlex1').jqGrid('editGridRow','"+cl+"',{top:top,left:left,width:420,height:220,reloadAfterSubmit:false,addedrow:'last',bSubmit:'Add' });" >E</button>";
            de = "<button style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' title='Delete' onclick="jQuery('#detFlex1').jqGrid('delGridRow','"+cl+"',{reloadAfterSubmit:false });" >D</button>";
            jQuery("#detFlex1").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{act:be+de});
        }
    },
    editurl: "<%= Html.Encode(ViewData["module"])%>/SaveDetail1"

});
jQuery("#detFlex1").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pagerFlex1', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false });
```

The edit button works wonderful, but the delete button is not.

The delete button when clicked, only makes a gray mask over the entire page, and not showing the delete confirmation dialog

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shouldn't you do this?

```
        be = "<button style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' title='Edit' onclick=\"jQuery('#detFlex1').jqGrid('editGridRow','"+cl+"',{top:top,left:left,width:420,height:220,reloadAfterSubmit:false,addedrow:'last',bSubmit:'Add' });\" >E</button>";
        de = "<button style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' title='Delete' onclick=\"jQuery('#detFlex1').jqGrid('delGridRow','"+cl+"',{reloadAfterSubmit:false });\" >D</button>";
```

(backslashes on the qoutes before and after the onclick event.)

I copied your method in my jqgrid (i dont delete in that grid normal) and it worked if i putted the backslashes. I got  the delete confirmation dialog.

But it's strange that the edit button works correctly without those backslashes...